# Method 'Boolean In[Int32](Int32, Int32[])' has no supported translation to SQL

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have the following method:

```
public List<Alert> GetMonthlyAlertsByAccountID(Int32 AccountID, params int[] alertTypes)
        {
            List<Alert> result = new List<Alert>();

            using (NeuroLabLinqDataContext dc = conn.GetContext())
            {
                IEnumerable<Alert> alerts = (from a in dc.Alerts
                                             where a.AccountID == AccountID &&
                                             a.AlertTypeID.In(alertTypes)
                                             orderby ((DateTime)a.CreateDate).Month ascending
                                             select a).ToList();
            }

            return result;
        }
```

That uses the extension method:

```
public static bool In<T>(this T t, params T[] values)
        {
            foreach (T value in values)
            {
                if (t.Equals(value))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

which has the purpose of only returning items with certain AlertTypeIDs.

The result is:

> Method 'Boolean In[Int32](Int32, Int32[])' has no supported
>   translation to SQL.

I am sure there is away to do with without having to use the extension method. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
alertTypes.Contains(a.AlertTypeID)
```

Instead.

```
IEnumerable<Alert> alerts = (from a in dc.Alerts
     where a.AccountID == AccountID &&
     alertTypes.Contains(a.AlertTypeID)
     orderby ((DateTime)a.CreateDate).Month ascending
     select a).ToList();
```